# Find order of columns in foreign key

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, metadata

I am trying to extract some meta data from Oracle about foreign keys. I am using the “all_constraints” to find all referential constraints information and “all_cons_columns” to find the actual columns. However, I can’t get the order of my columns in the foreign key.

Below are 4 example tables all with 3 columns. 3 of the tables reference the table “tab_d”, but the order of the columns in the foreign key differs. This order is not reflected in the “all_cons_columns” view, so is there another place where this information is available?

```
create table tab_d (
    col_a int,
    col_b int,
    col_c int,
    constraint tab_d_pk primary key (col_a, col_b, col_c)
);

create table tab_e (
    ref_col_a int,
    ref_col_b int,
    ref_col_c int,
    constraint tab_e_fk foreign key (ref_col_b, ref_col_c, ref_col_a)
        references tab_d(col_b, col_c, col_a)
);

create table tab_f (
    ref_col_a int,
    ref_col_b int,
    ref_col_c int,
    constraint tab_f_fk foreign key (ref_col_b, ref_col_c, ref_col_a)
        references tab_d(col_c, col_a, col_b)
);

create table tab_g (
    ref_col_a int,
    ref_col_b int,
    ref_col_c int,
    constraint tab_g_fk foreign key (ref_col_c, ref_col_b, ref_col_a)
        references tab_d(col_c, col_b, col_a)
);
```

The information i get from "all_cons_columns" is shown below and e.g. I my table “tab_g” where I thought position show the column order ref_col_c = 1, ref_col_b = 2 and ref_col_a = 3 it shows what order the column is in the primary key.

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME  POSITION
TAB_F_FK           TAB_F       REF_COL_A    2
TAB_F_FK           TAB_F       REF_COL_B    3
TAB_F_FK           TAB_F       REF_COL_C    1
TAB_E_FK           TAB_E       REF_COL_A    1
TAB_E_FK           TAB_E       REF_COL_B    2
TAB_E_FK           TAB_E       REF_COL_C    3
TAB_G_FK           TAB_G       REF_COL_A    1
TAB_G_FK           TAB_G       REF_COL_B    2
TAB_G_FK           TAB_G       REF_COL_C    3
```

Comment: The `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` results are showing you how the `COLUMN_NAME` in the child table maps to the column in the parent table's primary key, itself obtained from the `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` view. When you define your foreign key the order you list the columns makes no difference - it's only the mappings to the parent columns that matter so they just have to be in the same order in both clauses.

Comment: What is the significance of the order that columns are listed in the foreign key constraint definition?  The order that the columns are declared in the parent table affects how the index that enforces the primary key constraint is created by default.  If you create an index on the child table, you could get the order of the columns in that index.

Comment: I wanted the order of the columns for convenience, such that I was able to present the meta data as close to the create statements as possible, but if this is not possible I will just use the positions from “all_cons_columns” – Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the columns **is** reflected in the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS view - by the column called POSITION.